# Targetting an element within an Ajax control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to create a custom button in an Ajax HtmlEditorExtender control by locating the button container using its css class and appending a new button. However I am stuck at the first stage in that I cannot locate the container:

either in JQuery:

```
$btnContainer = $(".ajax__html_editor_extender_buttoncontainer");
window.alert($btnContainer.length);
```

Alert produces 0 even though there are buttons in the container

or in vanilla jscript:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("ajax__html_editor_extender_buttoncontainer");
                               window.alert(x.length);
```

alert again produces 0

Other elements on the page with css class names can be located in this way but the elements within the Ajax control cannot be found (even though they show up in Firebug with the above css class name).

Can anyone help please?

---

Added 04/06/15

Many thanks for the suggestions. Finding the control is indeed a timing and postback issue and not to do with getting the element within another control. If I strip out all except the vital bits, this is the code below.

Wherever I put the call to the JQ function, it cannot find the item wanted. None of the (commented out) ways of calling it work. Only if launched from a button on the page will it work. Have also tried calling the JQ from codebehind at page.LoadComplete but that is also too soon it seems.

Any help appreciated.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="EventsEdit.aspx.vb" Inherits="admin_EventsEdit"
    ValidateRequest="false" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function showcontainerJQ() {
            $btnContainer = $(".ajax__html_editor_extender_buttoncontainer");
            alert($btnContainer.length);
            $btnContainer.append("<input id=\"HtmlEditorExtender_H1\" class=\"ajax__html_editor_extender_YourButtonName\" type=\"button\" name=\"YourButtonName\" title=\"YourButtonName\" style=\"width: 21px; height: 21px;\" unselectable=\"on\"></input>");
        }

        //window.onload = showcontainerJQ();
        //document.onload = showcontainerJQ();
        //body.onload = showcontainerJQ();
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .ajax__html_editor_extender_HtmlEditorExtender_H1
        {
            background: url('/images/YourButtonName_off.png') no-repeat scroll;
            cursor: hand;
            display: block;
            float: right; /* default is left */
            border: medium none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

        <input type="button" onclick="showcontainerJQ()";value="H1"; > add button</input>
        <br /><br />

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="400px" Text='<%# Bind("eventText") %>'
            Width="265px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="TextBox1_HtmlEditorExtender" DisplaySourceTab="true"
            EnableSanitization="false" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
            <Toolbar>
            </Toolbar>
        </asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are probably adding the elements dynamically after the JS has been initially interpreted.  This would mean you need to try and listen to when they have been added first.

Comment: The other possibility is that those elements are inside an iframe. If they are, you won't be able to directly query them from the top-level document.

Comment: Most probably, `$btnContainer` has been initialized before the `ajax__html_editor_extender_buttoncontainer` is added to the `DOM`

Comment: Can we see your HTML? I want to know where your `<script>` tag is being loaded, or maybe it's a simple typo error.

Comment: Many thanks for replies and useful input - I added the code as an extension of the original posting.